# How to setup IPSec with Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipsec, openswan

How to setup an IPSec connection from my ubuntu laptop to Amazon EC2 instance? I tried setting it up using elastic IP and VPC with the following openswan configuration but it is not working.

> conn host-to-host
>
> ```
>     left=%defaultroute
>     leftsubnet=EC2PRIVATEIP/32 # Local netmask
>     leftid=ELASTICIP
>     leftrsasigkey=
>     connaddrfamily=ipv4
>     right=1laptopip # Remote IP address
>     rightid=laptopip
>     rightrsasigkey=
>     ike=aes128 # IKE algorithms (AES cipher)
>     esp=aes128 # ESP algorithns (AES cipher)
>     auto=add
>     pfs=yes
>     forceencaps=yes
>     type=tunnel
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have published a startup script to setup an Amazon EC2 instance with IPSec/L2TP VPN. You can do it in less than 5 minutes, you dont even need to actually log into the machine.

The good thing with IPSec/L2TP: it works out of the box for most clients (tested with Mac OS Lion and Mountain Lion, not Linux yet).

You can get it [here](https://github.com/sarfata/voodooprivacy) and get some background information about it on [this site](http://www.sarfata.org/posts/setting-up-an-amazon-vpn-server.md)